# Tridion schema design for multiple categories/keywords

Tags: tridion

We're looking at a content taxonomy that at first glance would use several different categories.

As a schema field where the value comes from a category can only be linked to a single category, this would mean a non-mandatory field for each category in my schema.

As an alternative, I'm thinking about one super-single category and parent keywords to store my complete taxonomy - this way I can have a single, multi-value schema field (select box or tree) and editors can do all their content tagging at once.

Could this affect our API queries when retrieving content? 
Has anyone taken this approach before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will certainly make your life simpler to use a single field/category, and you can set the root keywords as Abstract to ensure your clients don't use those keywords...

Words of caution:

- If you intend to use the Taxonomy objects, a first-time load will read all keywords. If you have a very large list of keywords this will certainly have an impact in performance, JVM usage, etc.
- You *really* want to have your cache properly configured

If you're going to use simple category/keyword queries then performance should be just about the same on a small vs large category. Same warning about cache applies.